Tangent space of Lie group SO(n)
I have a potentially simple question here, about the tangent space of the Lie group SO(n), the group of orthogonal $n\times n$ real matrices (I'm sure this can be asked more generally). For any $R\in \mathrm{SO}(n)$ we have $R^T R = R R^T = I$, where $I$ is the identity. I'm interested in the tangent space of SO(n) at some arbitrary rotation $R$.
Following two different derivations I get that the tangent space is either given by (1) Matrices of the form $R S$ where $S$ is skew symmetric; or (2) Matrices of the form $S R$ where $S$ is skew symmetric. These come from either starting the derivation of the tangent space from $RR^T =I$ or from $R^T R=I$ (see below). Can someone explain what these conventions are and how one basically enforces either (1) or (2)? I feel that for any $R\in SO(n)$ both $RR^T =I$ and $R^T R=I$ are true, but they lead to different outcomes.
Just as an example, to get (1) one could consider a curve $R_t$ that goes through $R$ at $t=0$. We have $R_t R_t^T = I$ for all $t$. Taking the derivative wrt $t$ we get $\dot{R}_t R_t^T + R_t \dot{R}_t^T = 0$. This yields $\dot{R}_t R_t^T = -(\dot{R}_t R_t^T)^T$. Therefore, $\dot{R}_t R_t^T = S_t$ for some skew symmetric matrix $S_t$, and finally $\dot{R}_t = S_t R_t$. Taking $t=0$ and considering all possible curves leads to the fact that the tangent space at $R$ is given by matrices of the form $SR$, where different elements in this space differ on the skew-symmetric matrix part of $S R$ (i.e. different matrices $S$).
On the other hand, if we simply start from $R_t^T R_t = I$ (instead of $R_t R_t^T = I$), and follow pretty similar steps, we get $\dot{R}_t = R_t S_t$.
Can someone point me in the right direction regarding why this comes up and how to understand this? For any $R\in \mathrm{SO}(n)$ both $R R^T=I$ and $R^T R=I$ hold. However, depending on which one I use I get a different expression for the tangent space.
Edit: This was answered in a comment below. The two ways of expressing the tangent space are equivalent, since $RS = S'R$ for $S'=RSR^\top$.

We have $RS = S'R$ where $$S' = RSR^T$$

@FrancescoPolizzi that was easy thanks! So the two ways to look at the tangent space are indeed equivalent, which can be seen using the construction you showed. Should that be an answer? I feel that perfectly answers the question.

The tangent space of a smooth manifold at a point is the set of all possible directions in which a curve can be drawn through that point. The tangent space of $SO(n)$ at a point $R$ is the set of all matrices of the form $R\Omega$, where $\Omega$ is a skew-symmetric matrix.
To prove this, we can consider a smooth curve $\gamma(t)$ in SO(n) such that $\gamma(0) = R$. The tangent vector to this curve at $t = 0$ is given by the derivative of $\gamma(t)$ with respect to $t$, evaluated at $t = 0$.
$\gamma'(0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\gamma(h) - \gamma(0)}{h}$
Since $\gamma(t)$ is in $SO(n)$, we have $\gamma(t)^T \gamma(t) = I$ for all $t$. Differentiating both sides with respect to $t$ and evaluating at $t = 0$, we get:
$\gamma'(0)^T \gamma(0) + \gamma(0)^T \gamma'(0) = 0$
This implies that $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$ are orthogonal. $\gamma'(0)^T = -\gamma'(0)$, which means that $\gamma'(0)$ is a skew-symmetric matrix.
The specific process is, $γ'(0)^T γ(0) + γ(0)^T γ'(0) = 0$
Multiplying both sides by $γ(0)$ from the right and $\gamma'(0)$ to left, then $γ'(0)^T + γ'(0) = 0$
Therefore, the tangent space of $SO(n)$ at $R$ consists of all matrices of the form $R\Omega$, where $\Omega$ is a skew-symmetric matrix.
